# python class inheritance def __init bit?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am using  Python 3 with PyQt4 and :

I have a first class :

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
```

with this function in it :

```
def Fn_GetSpnBitsValue(self):
        print (self.SpnBits.value())
        self.BitNumber =self.SpnBits.value()
        print(self.BitNumber)
        return self.BitNumber
```

as you can see I return the value of one of my spinners created in this class
Now I want to access this variable "self.BitNumber" from another class. 
In other language I would very simply write myValue = MainWindow.self.BitNumber but it seems it wont be as easy in python, so  I have look at class inheritance so my second class inherit of my first one...

I would be very tempted to write like this ... :

```
class BitsWindow(QtGui.QWidget, MainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):
        super(BitsWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI2()
```

Which makes perfect sens to me, I tell my second class "look you inherit from this class so everything she know, you know it as well" but I then get this message error :

```
 class BitsWindow(QtGui.QWidget, MainWindow):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases QWidget, MainWindow
```

Which don't really make any sens to me actually. By looking further on the web I have think understand the key is in that bit :

```
def __init__(self):
        super(BitsWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI2()
```

But I really struggle understanding the concept, I am not sure what this is doing despite numerous tutorials and forum answers. (Maybe, probably, didn't find the good ones.)

Any help would be much appreciated;

Many Thanks !

Comment: you should mention the python version and the Qt bindings package (PySide, PyQt4, PyQt5).

Comment: Apologize that's very true : Python 3 with PyQt4 (adding in the post too). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that `BitsWindow` inherits from `QWidget` and `MainWindow`, even though `MainWindow` already is a `QWidget`.

This spoils python's strategy to determine which e.g. which `__init__` method it should use, the one of `QWidget` or the one from `MainWindow`:

The `MainWindow` definition tells python to take `MainWindow` before the ones of `QWidget`.
When you define `BitsWindow(QWidget, MainWindow)` you give `QWidget` precedence over `MainWindow`. 
These two strategies collide and that's why you get the error.

So, simply change your class definition from

```
class BitsWindow(QtGui.QWidget, MainWindow):
...
```

to

```
class BitsWindow(MainWindow):
...
```

FWIW, you could also keep the redundant `QWidget` inheritance if you really want to, if you change the order:

```
class BitsWindow(MainWindow, QWidget):
    ...
```

should also work.

**EDIT:**

Inheritance may however not actually be what you want.
You can get that result be simply accessing it from an instance of `MainWindow`:

```
main = MainWindow()
myValue = main.Fn_GetSpnBitsValue()
```

or

```
main.Fn_GetSpnBitsValue()
myValue = main.BitNumber
```

Comment: Ha yes of course! Because MainWindow is already inheriting from QtGui.QWidget !
But now my issue is, I get all the layout/buttons...baically a copy past of my whole first class in my second class while I only want to access the result of one function.

Comment: Thanks I see better now. so I simply need to instantiate my class for accessing stuff in it. That makes sens indeed. 
Just one thing that bother me, the result of my function I am accessing is not the same weither I am printing it directly in the first class or in the second one. Accessing Fn_GetSpnBitsValue() from my second class will always return me the default value of my spinner (1) no matter what value is actually in it.

Comment: Hi, still an issue with your answer actually. 
main = MainWindow()
myValue = main.Fn_GetSpnBitsValue()
or

main.Fn_GetSpnBitsValue()
myValue = main.BitNumber

Doing so get myValue in a new instance of my first class rather than getting it from the existing current first class :/